# Installing Ubuntu on 24GB mSSD Hardware Acceleration Cache

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, hp, ssd

I bought an [HP ENVY TouchSmart 15t-j000 Quad Edition Notebook PC](http://www.shopping.hp.com/en_US/home-office/-/products/Laptops/HP-ENVY/E4T18AV?HP-ENVY-TouchSmart-15t-j000-Quad-Edition-Notebook-PC) laptop with a 24GB mSSD customization. I want to install Ubuntu in a dual boot setup alongside the existing Windows 8 OS.

I've disabled Secure Boot and Intel Smart Response Technology, but when I try to install Ubuntu, I'm unable to identify any 24GB partition into which I can install / (the root partition).

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to do a dual boot or a single boot install?

Comment: dual boot it. I do want to retain windows 8 also.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly if you are using 13.04 (or 12.10) then there's no need to disable secure boot - in fact Windows 8 won't boot with it disabled AFAIK.
When you boot from the CD and go into Files, is the SSD shown there?

You might also want to read this thread:
[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)